# Pushwoosh get Additional data - Custom data

Tags: android, ios, pushwoosh

I'm using Pushwoosh to send notification both under Android and iOS.

Now it's possible to send **Custom data** under the **Additional data** tab of the **Send push** web page.

So I put some like this

```
{"event" : "1234"}
```

on the Custom data field but I can't get this kind of data on the app.

This is what I get under **Android**

```
{
"title":"test 4",
"collapse_key":"do_not_collapse",
"from":"320152062216",
"onStart":true,
"foreground":false,
"p":"f"
}
```

This is what I get under **iOS**

```
{
    aps =     {
        alert = "test 4";
        sound = default;
    };
    p = f;
}
```

Is there anyone who has managed to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Stack might be not the best place for this, but custom data is available only on Premium accounts.

Comment: Custom data are available to free accounts too.

Comment: I very sorry but it's not.

Comment: Ok, Pushwoosh guys fixed the issue on the web interface so, now, free accounts are not able to send additional data.
But as I started the question that option was available for free accounts too.

Comment: @OscarPeli it's still free till the moment for me.

Comment: We are talking of Custom Data on the Additional Data tab.
With a free account you CANNOT send custom data with your push.
Before my question the field was enabled so this makes me crazy.
Now the field is disabled for free accounts